# Android: My Help Page comes up BLANK!

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create a very simple help page in my app. The layout xml for the page contains only a textview that displays the help info. In the Eclipse layout view, the layout looks perfect... however, when i try to load it in the emulator (via an OptionsMenu) it comes up as a blank black screen. What am I doing wrong??

Here is the Code:

```
//This is my Help page code

package com.soapbox.servicerec;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class HelpPage extends Activity {

 private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;

 private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;


  protected void onCreate(){
   setContentView(R.layout.help_page);
         setTitle(R.string.help_title);
           }

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
         menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
         return true;
}
  public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
         switch(item.getItemId()) {
             case INSERT_ID:
                 createNote();
                 return true;
         }
         return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
  }
  private void createNote() {
         Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
         startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);

     }
}
```

AND the layout XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"

     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@android:color/white">

   <TextView android:textSize="16px" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingLeft="10px" 
   android:paddingRight="10px" android:text="@string/help_text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I assume you're `@Override` ing all those methods in your activity, just didn't copy paste them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have your `onCreate()` function defined as ::

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help_page);
        setTitle(R.string.help_title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `onCreate` method signature is wrong.

notice the difference below

your method `protected void onCreate()`

proper way `@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

The `@Override` notation is optional, but very useful because it ensure the method signature matches one from a parent class, helping prevent these situations.

Comment: Thank you so much... I am trying to teach myself Java/Android programming via the tutorials and a lot of trial and error. I really appreciate all the help from people on this site!

One last question: What is the purpose of the (Bundle savedInstanceState) bit and what exactly was causing my method to fail?

Comment: The bundle is so you can save your activity state between activity states. Your method isn't failing, it's just not being called. You have to override the class method